# Auto select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

I would need a little help to automatically select a value based on input data.

I have a form to fill in the postal code. According to the first 2 digits of the postal code I would like to select the value that best matches.

```
<input id="postalcode" placeholder="postal code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" />
<select id="agence">
<option value="0" selected="" disabled>Séléctionnez votre concession</option>
  <option value="TYRYT" data-dep="01" >01 - Agence A</option>
  <option value="GTJG" data-dep="01">01 - Agence B</option>
  <option value="TYF7" data-dep="01">01 - Agence C</option>
  <option value="CYVK" data-dep="66">66 - Agence D</option>
  <option value="VCHDX" data-dep="66">66 - Agence E</option>
  <option value="GVJR" data-dep="78">78 - Agence F</option>
  <option value="HJGG" data-dep="79">79 - Agence G</option>
  <option value="VJYJV" data-dep="79">79 - Agence H</option>
</select>
```

If I write 01789 in postalcode input , the first value containing "01" must be selected:

```
<option value="TYRYT" data-dep="01" >01 - Agence A</option>
```

If I write 54879 in postalcode, the closest value must be selected:

```
 <option value="CYVK" data-dep="66">66 - Agence D</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this (there are plenty of other options/solutions/micro-optimised)

- get the input
- extract the first 2 characters
- loop through all the options to find those with matching `data-dep`
- use the first one found

```js
$(function() {
    $("#postalcode").on("input", function() {
        var prefix = $(this).val().substr(0,2);
        //console.log(prefix, $("#agence option[data-dep=" + prefix + "]").length);
        
        var opts = $("#agence option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).data("dep") == prefix;
        });

        // this will break if user enters something other than a number, eg "]"
        // var opts = $("#agence option[data-dep=" + prefix + "]");
       
        if (opts.length) $("#agence").val(opts[0].value)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="postalcode" placeholder="postal code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" />
<select id="agence">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled>Séléctionnez votre concession</option>
  <option value="TYRYT" data-dep="01">01 - Agence A</option>
  <option value="GTJG" data-dep="01">01 - Agence B</option>
  <option value="TYF7" data-dep="01">01 - Agence C</option>
  <option value="CYVK" data-dep="66">66 - Agence D</option>
  <option value="VCHDX" data-dep="66">66 - Agence E</option>
  <option value="GVJR" data-dep="78">78 - Agence F</option>
  <option value="HJGG" data-dep="79">79 - Agence G</option>
  <option value="VJYJV" data-dep="79">79 - Agence H</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Perfect ! 
Thank you so much !